# 2005 toyota camry 3.0l bank 1 sensor 2 where is it

Tags: toyota, exhaust, camry, o2-sensor

i have a 2005 toyota camry v6 3.0l it needs a bank 1 sensor 2 where is it or which one on the exhaust is it. im not sure about words like downstream just want to make sure

Answer (score 1):

It is the one between the catalytic converter and muffler/exhaust tip.

"Downstream" indicates that it is the sensor which is further away from the engine.

The "upstream" sensor will be between the exhaust headers and catalytic converter (marked "TWC" in the example image below).

[image: Sample exploded view]

Comment: You can directly relate "upstream" and "downstream" to their position in relationship to the catalytic converter. Upstream=before; downstream=after.